# Cannot get fullcalendar to display events from a Google calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

This is very odd. I am just trying to establish the basic functionality of fullcalendar with a shared Google calendar. I tried simply replacing the gcal demo "gcal.html" with my own calendar URL. The calendar opens fine on its own. Here is some code:

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='../jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            // US Holidays
            events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=r9k375tdhq8auc1oc4kgmhpri4%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Chicago',
            eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) {
                    $('#loading').show();
                }else{
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

I am pretty much assured that I have all the dependencies right, etc, because I am in the gcal demo. My calendar opens otherwise when I plug the URL into the address bar. This calendar is set to be public. Any help would be appreciated. Full calendar with Google calendars seems like a good pairing, if I could get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the right URL. FullCalendar wants an XML feed, not an entire calendar which is what you're giving it.

[See the documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/).

Try following these steps:

> You must first make your Google Calendar public:
>
> ```
> In the Google Calendar interface, locate the "My Calendar" box on the left.
> Click the arrow next to the calendar you need.
> A menu will appear. Click "Share this calendar."
> Check "Make this calendar public."
> Make sure "Share only my free/busy information" is unchecked.
> Click "Save."
> ```
>
> Then, you must obtain your calendar's XML feed URL:
>
> ```
> In the Google Calendar interface, locate the "My Calendar" box on the left
> Click the arrow next to the calendar you need.
> A menu will appear. Click "Calendar settings."
> In the "Calendar Address" section of the screen, click the XML badge.
> Your feed's URL will appear.
> ```

I believe this is the URL you want

[https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/r9k375tdhq8auc1oc4kgmhpri4%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/r9k375tdhq8auc1oc4kgmhpri4@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic)

Comment: Thanks Brandon! Knew it was something foolish, but my eyes would not see it. Thanks!

Comment: @Will, no problem. If this solved your problem, don't forget you can mark it as the accepted answer by selecting the checkmark.